# c# combine two results from two different database providers

Tags: c#

I need to check if something in one table (table 1) was added and if so I need to take some values from this table and insert it in the second table (table 2).
The problem is that the Table 1 is .DBF Provider=VFPOLEDB.1 connected by OleDbConnection and the second Table 2 is MSSQL table connected by SqlConnection.

I want to make something like this:
SELECT column1 FROM Table1 WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column2 FROM Table2)

Is it possible to do this? I can load both tables to the datagridview by doing:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableDBF(string strFileName)

    {

        OleDbConnection conFOX = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + Path.GetFullPath(strFileName).Replace(Path.GetFileName(strFileName), "") + ";Exclusive=No");

        conFOX.Open();

        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conFOX);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds);

        return ds.Tables[0];

    }
```

for OleDbConnection and doing:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableSQL(string TableName)

    {

        SqlConnection conSQL = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conSQL.Open();

        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName;
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conSQL);

        da.Fill(ds);

        return ds.Tables[0];

    }
```

for SqlConnection. Mayby I can do 2 datasets or something like temporary tables from this query? so it will be something like this? :

```
SELECT dataset1.column1 FROM dataset1 WHERE dataset1.column1 NOT IN (SELECT dataset2.column2 FROM dataset2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both datatables are from different sources you need to fetch both datatables into memory and then use linq to dataset. something like this

```
    var datatable1 = GetDataTableDBF("filename");
    var datatable2 = GetDataTableSQL("tablename");

    var query = from c in dataset1.AsEnumerable()
                where !(from o in dataset2.AsEnumerable()
                        select o.Field<int>("column2")).Contains(c.Field<int>("column1"))
                select c;

    var filteredDataTable1 = query.CopyToDataTable();

    var resultDataTable = filteredDataTable1.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "column1"); //create new table with only 1 column

    dataGridView1.DataSource = resultDataTable;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will test this out but I never used Linq before so can you explain this for me further? How can I use it, what provider or DataAdapter should I use to fill Dataset? I want to show that resoult in new DataGridView.

Comment: you already have 2 methods to get datatables.get 2 datatables using those methods and then linq query will give you the data you want.finally bind the query to your datagrid.

Comment: ok, but when I make:
'dvgTest.DataSource = datatable1;'
I get a DataTable1 result and it's ok. Same for datatable2. But when I make something easier in LINQ:
'var query = from c in datatable2.AsEnumerable()
                        select c;
dvgTest.DataSource = query;'
I won't get any results. Why?

Comment: Sorry but I figured out that I didn't put .ToList() at the end of query.
When I put query.ToList() I get a results by with column header like: RowError, RowState, Table, HasError. Why?

Comment: I have updated the answer.you should create datatable instead of list.